# notification push ruby on rails with firebase for ios and android

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, push-notification

hello I'm looking for a gem for push notifications from Ruby o​n Rails with firebase, I'm actually very new to notifications and the mobile devices I appreciate any help. I'm finishing a project and I just need that in the back-end.

I would like, for example, every time a service is registered by the client within the mobile app, I will generate a push notification where it says "a new service has been generated" and that all employees can see it

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use the rpush gem it's really easy to handle and very explanatory documentation I have been using this for a while and never faced any issue with it. We can easliy handle the ios/android notification by the single gem.

First you need install rpush and run this command bundle exec rpush init

Now write down a task to to add the firebase api-key

```
app = Rpush::Gcm::App.new
app.name = "android_app"
app.auth_key = "..."
app.connections = 1
app.save!
```

whenever you need to send the notification you need to use this method to push the notification in the notification table

```
n = Rpush::Gcm::Notification.new n.app = Rpush::Gcm::App.find_by_name("android_app")
n.registration_ids = ["..."]
n.data = { message: "hi mom!" }
n.priority = 'high'        # Optional, can be either 'normal' or 'high'
n.content_available = true # Optional
you can use!
n.notification = { body: 'great match!',
                   title: 'Portugal vs. Denmark',
                   icon: 'myicons'
                 }
n.save!
```

add this in application controller and call this method everywhere in the project.